# Execute sp_WhoIsActive as a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am at a client where they don't allow Adam Machanic's `sp_WhoIsActive` stored procedure to be installed anywhere on the SQL server. Does anyone have any suggestions for running it as a query instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can run any SP as a query by getting rid of the "CREATE PROCEDURE" part and defining all of the parameters as variables.

For example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test (@var1 int, @var2 int) AS
PRINT @var1
PRINT @var2
```

Would become

```
DECLARE @var1 int
DECLARE @var2 int
PRINT @var1
PRINT @var2
```

You might also ask them if it is ok if you create a "DBA" database for code like this and put the SP there.  That way the SP is on the instance and will run correctly, but is still segregated from the rest of their databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider removing [lines 9-10](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/blob/master/sp_WhoIsActive.sql#L9) and changing the `ALTER PROC dbo.sp_WhoIsActive` to `CREATE OR ALTER PROC #sp_WhoIsActive` to just create it as a `#temp` proc scoped to your session.

This doesn't create any persistent object (or any object in the user database at all or require permissions to `CREATE PROC` there).

You can then just call it and pass the desired parameters in the usual way.